# Does hard-coding the from email address avoid the PHPMailer vulnerability that was announced yesterday?

Tags: php, phpmailer

The announcement I am referring to was posted at:
http://legalhackers.com/advisories/PHPMailer-Exploit-Remote-Code-Exec-CVE-2016-10033-Vuln.html

I have used code like this in many websites:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->SetFrom('info@mysite.com', 'My Site');
$mail->AddReplyTo( $contact_email, "$contact_name" );
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->AltBody = $mail_text;
$mail->MsgHTML($mail_html);
$result = $mail->Send();
```

Am I safe from the vulnerability because my from address is hard-coded?  Should I worry about the reply-to address, which comes from user input?  I do validate it with filter_var, but if I understand correctly, a from address can pass validation and still inject code because spaces are technically allowed in email addresses.

Comment: Looks like you are safe to me, though I'm by no means an expert in this domain...

Comment: You should not *ever* let someone set the 'from' address in an email, regardless of a given mailer's security issues. It's a deliverability problem as properly implemented SPF and DMARC policies should preclude 3rd-party MTAs delivering mail on their behalf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are safe.

As Sammitch said, you should never use a user-supplied from address anyway because it will be forgery and you will fail SPF checks. This is mentioned in the PHPMailer docs and in many answers on SO.